# Why default language resource doesn't show up

Tags: android, string, internationalization, resources

my app supports for multiple languages, and English is the default language.
The problem happens when I add new strings, I only added to English resource, but why it does`t show up in other languages.

As I know, it should show the default string if it does`t have translated version.

But why this not happen?

thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to add new strings to all language string files that you want to show

Comment: Anytime you use `getString(R.string.xxx)` if it is not defined in your values-YY folder you should get your values folder value automatically

Comment: Add the `translatable="false"` attribute to your string in `values/strings.xml` (**this** is your fallback file, not `values-en/strings.xml`). Example: `<string name="app_name" translatable="false">My App</string>`